# Incomprehensible information in system diagnostic report

Tags: macos

When I open Console app and go to the "System diagnostic report" I can see awdd files. In the file while I can see for example:

> ($0éÞÊ ú©åÞ)ÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ (08@HPZða ¨ü1 ªÿÿz ¿´åÞ)($0ß     ¾´åÞ)
>   System Profile:
>   AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0

what is that mean the characters?! I can see this in each awdd file. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to find them incomprehensible - those are not plain text files but instead binary formatted files.

What you can do is focus on the high level task and see if you even need to look at those files in the first place. Usually there are easier options than reverse-engineering the binary format for debugging issues.